# Bound IntentService and ProgressBar without percentage

Tags: android, bind, intentservice

`onBind(Intent intent)` exists in `IntentService` class and [documented](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onBind%28android.content.Intent%29), I have tried writing code according to the [Bound Services pattern](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) but `onHandleIntent` containing expensive operations was not called.

1. Why? I wrote my own `BroadcastReceiver` to listen messages from the
   service. Is it a workaround or a good solution?
2. And the second question. How to refresh percentage on a `ProgressBar`?
   [setProgress(int value)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#setProgress%28int%29) didn't work as I expected. Should I use
   a `TextView` above the `ProgressBar`?

I am sorry, I've got much code to post it here, but I'll give the [github link](https://github.com/Red-Planet/Sandbox_Android/tree/test_intent_service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why?

Because `IntentService` is designed to be used with the command pattern, with you sending commands to the service via `startService()`. A call to `startService()` will trigger `onHandleIntent()`; nothing else will.

> I wrote my own BroadcastReceiver to listen messages from the service. Is it a workaround or a good solution?

Since it is unclear what you are talking about, I cannot answer that.

> How to refresh percentage on a ProgressBar?

Call `setProgress()`.

> setProgress(int value) didn't work as I expected.

Since you declined to explain what you expected, we cannot help you.

Comment: regarding the `BroadcastReceiver`, it is [on GitHub](https://github.com/Red-Planet/Sandbox_Android/tree/test_intent_service). And regarding the `ProgressBar`. I expected "progress / max" formatted text (e.g., "1 / 20") above the `ProgressBar`. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @RedPlanet: "I expected "progress / max" formatted text (e.g., "1 / 20") above the ProgressBar." -- `ProgressBar` does not have such text.

Comment: so I'll have to place an extra `TextView` above the `ProgressBar`